# Strange behavior of moments.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

```js
var now = moment({ year: 2018, month: 11, day: 9 }).format('M');
alert(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

The expected behavior is alert shows '11' but you can see shows '12'

Someone know why?

Comment: Months in JavaScript (and for [`moment(Object)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/)) are 0 indexed, so you are a creating a moment object that represents 2018-12-09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input of the month is from 0 to 11, when the output format is from 1 to 12.

```js
var now = moment({ year: 2018, month: 0, day: 9 }).format('M');

console.log(now);

now = moment({ year: 2018, month: 11, day: 9 }).format('M');

console.log(now);

now = moment({ year: 2018, month: 12, day: 9 }).format('M');

console.log(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

---

[Documentation about M format](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/)

[image]

[Documentation about Month input](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/)

[image]

---

---

To handle this case programmatically, you can either retrieve 1 to your month at the moment you set it or retrieve 1 at the end display.

Example :

```js
var now = moment({ year: 2018, month: 11 - 1, day: 9 }).format('M');

console.log(now);


var now = String(Number(moment({ year: 2018, month: 11, day: 9 }).format('M')) - 1);

console.log(now);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see.... Thanks a lot.... but then what is the best way to have from

var now = moment({ year: 2018, month: 11, day: 9 }) format to '2018-11-9'?

Comment: @JuanMedina I've made an edit with the answer to your question